# Express sending assets with wrong MIME type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, vue.js

Using Express to serve a Vue.js webpack app, I am receiving the following error after deploy:
[image]
Is my code for serving the app is the issue here?

```
app.use(helmet())

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist/static')));

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist', 'index.html'));
})
```

Otherwise isn't `express.static` supposed to automatically assign content types to the static files?

Comment: similar issue but my problem was overlooking that **express.static()** needs an absolute path.

Answer (score 6):

You get this message also when the response status in `404 Not Found`, so check carefully that the files actually exist from Network tab.

Network tab:

[image: status 404]

Console tab:

[image]

See a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48792698/258772

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, had to now specify a mount path:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist/static')));
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Clearing `npm cache` did not help, nor did reinstalling all `node_modules` - but giving it a mount path. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: What if I want to host the static files at the root of the app :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes same problems over here.

I'm using `ecstatic` (still with express) now. I'm not sure if this is the solution (I'm not on the machine that made the error possible).

Will try it tommorow on the 'error' machine.

```
const express = require('express');
const ecstatic = require('ecstatic');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();

app.use(ecstatic({
  root: `${__dirname}/public`,
  showdir: false,
}));

http.createServer(app).listen(8080);

console.log('See if its cool on -> :8080');
```