# Images don't load on local machine

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Website loads well css,js,imgs when I uploaded it to [Github](https://franky90.github.io/WorkoutProgrammer/), but when I start it at local server it loads only html without css,js, and images.

Because it was not loading and I've read a bit in internet I decided to add "public" folder and pack everything inside. Also I added in server.js

`app.use(express.static('public'));`

Errors:
For CSS
*Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.*

For imgs
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

JS functions doesn't work as well.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/", function(req,res){    
res.sendFile(__dirname  + "/index.html");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){

});
```

index.html

```
       
    <meta charset=“UTF-8”>
    <meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <title>Workout Programmer</title>
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nanum+Gothic+Coding:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    
</head>
```

I've tried to change path to ./ or ../ or without "/" or /public etc... nothing worked.

and at the bottom index.html

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>`

img link:

```
<img src="/images/workoutman.png" alt="workoutman"
```

All files are stored in folder called "public" , and images are in public/images

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node/Express - Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778619/node-express-refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html)

Comment: In server.js I've changed : 
`app.use(express.static('public')); `
to 
`app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

It fixed problem in half way. Images and JS loads now, but CSS still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the I finally fixed the problem.
In file server.js I used

> app.use(express.static(__dirname));

Other problem was styles.css actually wasn't in public folder as I thought. VisualStudio interface lost me a bit.
To find it out lead me this tip:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60821720/14340165