# Applying static folder within nodejs / express

Tags: css, node.js, express, routes

I'm having trouble getting the CSS and JS to apply within routing of my nodejs project.
I've tried the following lines:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname, '/public));
```

Am I forgetting to do something? My client console says this: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/users/css/styles.css'  My CSS file is not in the users folder though. Its in a folder called 'public' in the same directory as my 'server.js' file.

```
const express = require('express');

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/home');
});

// This code works, but I want to apply different routing
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/register');
});

// This code will render the page, however CSS and JS files don't apply
app.get('/users/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/register');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is currently running on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778619/node-express-refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html

Comment: @crg Thank you! That helped! I actually just had to add a forward slash at the beginning of my css link. I originally had css/styles.css. Where it had to be /css/styles.css.

Answer (score 0):

@Vince found the answer in [Node/Express - Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778619/node-express-refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html) changing  `css/styles.css` by `/css/styles.css`