# Express not serving compiled Angular files

Tags: angular, express

I have compiled my Angular FE and placed it in the nodejs BE public folder which is accessible from browser:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

and set up express to serve the content:

```
app.use('', (req, res, next) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/clientApp', 'index.html'));
    });
```

But I'm getting this puzzling errors in the browser console:

```
Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/runtime-es2015.e3e9ca9bbd4db2ff1ff0.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/polyfills-es2015.6db406a075ad3aed7ba9.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/main-es2015.2b6d7bc5e864e8a8e238.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

Not sure what's going on...

Comment: probably the path to your static files is incomplete. Pls check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894236/express-sending-assets-with-wrong-mime-type

Comment: Did your code are in production mode or development ?

Comment: @Borys Kupar that didn't help. the index.html get's loaded, but all the .js and .css files it links to don't. they're all right there next to index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here's what it was. as often console errors didn't help a bit. so, just marking top level directory

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

as static wasn't enough when loading external js and css. I also had to mark subdirectory where the compiled js and css files are as static (although it's static already)

```
app.use(express.static('public/clientApp'));
```